# Div is not automatic height as specified

Tags: html, css

I cannot seem to get my div's height to set automatically.

despite setting a min-height and

```
height:auto
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear your floats or set `overflow: auto` to your parent container:

```
#Mid_Container {
    width:1048px;
    height:auto;
    min-height:1100px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:15px;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid #a9a9a9;
    background-color:#f7f7f7;
    overflow: auto; /* cause this block to enclose floated child elements */
}
```

Modified jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/JRd9z/1/

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you. It seems as though the div doesn't know what to do when overflow isn't set?

Comment: Actually, floated elements do not contribute to the computed height of the parent/containing block element.  In your case, the factor contributing to the height is the min-height value.  Setting `overflow: auto` establishes a new block formatting context which encloses all the floats. Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting